# Getting values from PHP multidimensional array

Tags: php, arrays, string, multidimensional-array, foreach

I have one Array just like the one above:

```
Array
(
    [4] => Array
        (
            [p] => 0
            [c] => 
        )

    [5] => Array
        (
            [p] => 0
            [c] => gh1
        )
)
```

I am trying to retrieve using PHP the [4] or [5] from the array programmatically, but if i use foreach() from the array, I will not get the figures desired (4 and 5)
Using a

```
foreach ($array as $k) {
   echo '-->' . $k->p . ' ' . $k->c . '<br/>'
}
```

will show only

```
--> 0 
--> 0 gh1
```

I want to have this:

```
--> [4] 0
--> [5] 0 gh1
```

Could someone help me?

Comment: your question is unclear. Please edit.

Comment: Not sure to understand what is your problem exactly ? _get the figures desired_

Comment: Your question isn't clear: please explain what values you are trying to retrieve

Comment: Added some explains, hope you all are now clear

Comment: @rosuandreimihai check my answer, it solved your problem

Comment: Why should I check your answer if I already marked my own response as the one desired for my piece of code?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I managed to figure out the right way to do this:

```
foreach (array_keys($array) as $key) {
}
```

and it will give us the figures desired

Comment: Why should it be bad?? And why am I being penalized for a solution from PHP Manual?? Check the link below please
http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-keys.php

Comment: Because using array_keys() will create a whole new array with the keys in the memory, it's much less memory efficient on larger arrays. Instead, the foreach loop as suggested by koljanep adds only the key and the value to the memory. It's the same footprint for any size of the array, instead of a memory footprint dependent of the size of the array.

Answer (score 3):

This is the answer:

```
foreach ($array as $key=>$value) {
   echo '--> [' . $key . '] ' . $value["p"] . ' ' . $value["c"] . '<br/>';
}
```

See explanation here:
http://php.net/manual/en/control-structures.foreach.php

> The foreach construct provides an easy way to iterate over arrays.
>   ...
>   There are two syntaxes:
>
> foreach (array_expression as $value)
>       statement
>
> foreach (array_expression as $key => $value)
>       statement
>
> ...
>
> The second form will additionally assign the current element's key to
>   the $key variable on each iteration.

Comment: added explanation. Yes I missed the semicolon, fixed that too. I copied his example from above of the loop he used and just fixed the key=>value. Didn't see that it was missing the `;`

Comment: thank you for your answer, it is another way of doing it

Comment: $value is not an object is an array, check your code

Answer (score 2):

This code is more general, because you can have others indexes in the array distinct to c and d. Take a look.

```
  foreach ($array as $key => $value) {
       echo '--->[' . $key . '] ';
       foreach($value as $info => $inside) {
         echo  $inside . ' ';
       }
       echo '<br/>';
    }
```

Comment: @rosuandreimihai you solved your problem? Don't forget check the answer as correct ;-)

Comment: Sorry, my solution works fine for what I want. Thank you, but the answer is already checked!